# Fastest method to remove rows that are slightly different by a given threshold epsilon

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, diff, distinct

In my data, I have multiple rows that are only slightly different from each others e.g. 0.001. I want to keep only 1 record if that happens. Is there any existing function/package that can do row-wise comparison and removes rows if the differences are smaller than a given threshold epsilon? I was thinking something like `distinct(., epsilon = 0.001)`

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  IDname = c("aaa1", "bbb2", "ccc3", "ddd4"),
  g = c(0.00501, 0.00499, 2, 2),
  t = c(0.005002, 0.004991, 2.001, 2.0001),
  x = c(1.0001, 1, 2, 2.00001)
)

df
```

Desired output:

```
  IDname       g        t       x
1   aaa1 0.00501 0.005002 1.00010
3   ccc3 2.00000 2.001000 2.00000
```

Comment: Your example and output seem inconsistent. With `epsilon = 0.0001`, rows 3 and 4 are different, are they not? Only values in rows 1 and 2 are similar within `epsilon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a mistake in OP's example (see my comment above), here is a solution using `duplicated` on the `paste`d row values.

Will remove if OP clarifies and I misunderstood the question.

```
# Your data
df <- data.frame(
  IDname = c("aaa1", "bbb2", "ccc3", "ddd4"),
  g = c(0.00501, 0.00499, 2, 2),
  t = c(0.005002, 0.004991, 2.001, 2.0001),
  x = c(1.0001, 1, 2, 2.00001)
)

df[!duplicated(apply(round(df[, -1], 3), 1, paste, collapse = "_")), ];
#  IDname       g        t       x
#1   aaa1 0.00501 0.005002 1.00010
#3   ccc3 2.00000 2.001000 2.00000
#4   ddd4 2.00000 2.000100 2.00001
```

---

More generally for any tolerance `epsilon`:

```
epsilon <- 0.0001;
df[!duplicated(apply(round(df[, -1], -log10(epsilon) - 1), 1, paste, collapse = "_")), ];
```

---

**Method using hierarchical clustering** (inspired by @BenoitLondon)

We can use hierarchical clustering using a euclidean distance matrix and complete linkage to cluster observations (rows) by similarity.

```
# Calculate euclidean distance matrix
dist <- dist(df[, -1], method = "euclidean");

# Perform hierarchical clustering with complete linkage
hc <- hclust(dist, method = "complete");
```

We can now cut the tree by recognising that the maximum euclidean distance between two *similar* observations is given by `dmax = sqrt(sum_m epsilon^2) = sqrt(m) * epsilon`, where `m` are the number of (numeric) columns. We can therefore cut the tree at a height `h = dmax`.

```
# Cut the tree
epsilon <- 0.0001;
grp <- cutree(hc, h = sqrt(ncol(df[, -1])) * epsilon);
grp;
#[1] 1 1 2 3
```

The collapsed `dataframe` is then

```
df[!duplicated(grp), ];
#  IDname       g        t       x
#1   aaa1 0.00501 0.005002 1.00010
#3   ccc3 2.00000 2.001000 2.00000
#4   ddd4 2.00000 2.000100 2.00001
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I updated my question and included a new column with ID. Could you modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: The original example and output still don't match (rows 3 and 4 are still different within `epsilon`). I've made changes to account for column `IDname` and for arbitrary tolerance `epsilon`.

Comment: Thanks! That should do it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @thecatalyst No worries. Glad to help.

Comment: weird behavior for values around half integers
if you make `df <- data.frame(a= 0:10, b = 0.001*0:10, c = 1); epsilon = 0.001` it keeps 2 rows with 0 and 6. I think the question is ill-posed but maybe it works in this special case, though a general answer would involve clustering imho.

Comment: @BenoitLondon I'm not following you. In your example, if I do `epsilon <-
 0.001; df[!duplicated(apply(round(df, -log10(epsilon) - 1), 1, paste, collapse = "_")), ];` I keep all rows (as expected). Note that in OP's example, I *excluded* the first ID column (as per OP's request); in your example you need to *include all columns*.

Comment: @BenoitLondon You might be interested in the (hierarchical) clustering approach that I added (inspired by your clustering idea).

Comment: Thanks! Applying your function with `epsilon = 0.001` gave the desired result

Comment: @MauritsEvers after thinking about the epsilon, maybe percentage difference between corresponding elements in rows would be better. What do you think?

Comment: @thecatalyst That really depends on what you're trying to do, and where those numbers come from. Perhaps it makes sense to scale all columns to have zero mean and unit variance, and then use a global `epsilon` as a fraction of `sd` to collapse "similar rows".

Answer (score 2):

why just no `round` the values + `unique`?

```
df <- data.frame(

  g = c(1.001, 1, 2.00001, 2),
  t = c(1, 1.001, 2.001, 2.0001),
  x = c(1.0001, 1, 2, 2.00001)
)

vect <- sapply(df, function(x) unique(round(x, 2)) )
data.frame(vect)
```

this works only when the length of each column is equal.

Comment: answer is wrong as if you change the second g value to 2 you will get the same result. The unique needs to be applied on the rows of the data.frame. Also if vaues are each side of an half integer the values would not be assumed equal. ( like 0.49999 and 0.50001 will become 0 and 1 instead of both 0.5) though if the question author assumes values are close to integer then it's fine but again it does not handle the epsilon tolerance

Comment: Thanks @W W and @BenoitLondon for the help! I edited my question for more generic cases which make this solution didn't work anymore

Comment: @BenoitLondon there is `round(x, 2)` actually so for 0.49999 and 0.50001 it will be: 0.50 and 0.50 :)